# Generate custom auto number

Tags: vb.net

I want to generate auto_no by coding.
So I will need to get previous auto_no from sql server then auto_no + 1 to generate next number.
But since my database does not have any record yet. So the temp should be equal to 1.
But why i get temp = 0?

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(myConn)
    Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim temp As Int64

    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT MAX(Auto_No) FROM Quotation_No"
   Dim comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        con.Open()
        myReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        If myReader.HasRows Then
            Do While myReader.Read()
            Loop
    Else
        temp = 1
    End If

    Frm1.txtQuotation_No.Text = temp
    con.Close()
```

Comment: What is your question? You posted your code, which is great, but please edit your post such that it can be understood more easily.

Comment: Since there is no rows yet in your database, `myReader.HasRows` should return `False`. Check out what is returned by `myReader.HasRows`. Superficially, this condition appears to be evaluated to `True` for some reason.

Comment: myReader.HasRows returns true.but my database does not have any record yet.

Comment: Try on the backend database system directly this query, `SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM Quotation_No` and see what is returned by it.

Comment: Essentially the `max()` function returns a row (with even `null`) even though there are no rows in the underlying database table. So, this condition `myReader.HasRows` will be true even though there are no rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the first call to myReader.Read() that is your problem.

Your reader always returns 1 row (even if there are no rows in the database it will return a result (either 0 or null)).

What your code is doing is as follows:

1. Executes the command - it returns 1 row.
2. Calls myReader.Read() which reads the first row
3. Calls myReader.HasRows which returns true since it has one row
4. The code enters the if block and calls myReader.Read(), which returns false since you've already read the one row returned in step 4.
5. The while loop exits.
6. temp is never set as is left as zero.

Comment: so what should i change for my coding?

Comment: Get rid of the first call to myReader.Read()